# Specify dynamic url in form action

Tags: html

I am trying to specify a dynamic url in the actions properties of form.
The url will be dependant on what the user enters in the textbox. For example, if the user enters `"Fred"` as `firstname` and `1234` as `courseId`, then the url should be `"/users/Fred/course/1234"`

This is what I have so far but it is not reading the firstname and courseId.

```
    <form action="/users/{{firstname}}/course/{{courseId}}" method="POST">
        <input type="text" placeholder="firstname" name="firstname">
        <input type="email" placeholder="email" name="email">
        <input type="text" placeholder="courseId" name="courseId">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

No php and ajax can be used.

Comment: are you using angular or something apart from html?

Comment: I'm using the hbs module from node.js.

Comment: What happens when two users share the same first name and are in the same class? Use a user id instead of firstname.

Answer (score 1):

You need javascript to do this

```js
const template = (firstname, courseId) => `/users/${firstname}/course/${courseId}`;

document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', function(s) {
  s.preventDefault();
  this.action = template(this.elements["firstname"].value, this.elements["courseId"].value);
  this.submit();
});
```

```html
<form action="placeholder" method="POST" id="myForm">
  <input type="text" placeholder="firstname" name="firstname">
  <input type="email" placeholder="email" name="email">
  <input type="text" placeholder="courseId" name="courseId">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: where is 'placeholder' being called?

Comment: Never @DanCode .

Comment: @DanCode what do you want to do with `placeholder`?

Comment: the placeholder should be the url of the webpage.

Comment: placeholder will be replaced on submit @DanCode